# Android playing audio and recordning audio at the same time

Tags: android, background-process, audio-recording, audio-player

How to record audio and playing sound at the same time. Which process is better to implement in background and what to use Thread or AsyncTask? I haved tried playing sound in new thread and recordning on main thread but i have problem that on some devices i get error that the main thread is overload.

Is it better to use native rocordning, because i also need recorded buffer?

Does anybody have any example how to use native recording?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following custom class:-

```
package com.app.controller;
```

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MediaController implements OnPreparedListener{

```
public MediaController() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MediaPlayer mp;

public void getMediaPlayObject() {

    try {
        System.out.println("00000000000000");
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        System.out.println("2222222222");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("exception in audia player====" + e.toString());
    }
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    mp.start();
}

boolean WORKING = true;

public void mediaPlayStart(final Context m_Context) {
    try {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        mp.setDataSource(m_Context, Uri.parse(Contants.audioURL_OR_PATH));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setLooping(true);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(m_Context, "Service unavailable this time. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("#####THE EXCEPTION IN THE MEDIA PLAYER PLAY==="+e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void mediaPlayStop() {
    try {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

private static String getSoundPath(int countPositiong) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String aa = "";

    try {
        if (countPositiong < 10) {
            aa = "sounds/00" + countPositiong + ".mp4";
        } else if (countPositiong < 100) {
            aa = "sounds/0" + countPositiong + ".mp4";
        } else {
            aa = "sounds/" + countPositiong + ".mp4";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    System.out.println("name is : " + aa);
    return aa;

}
```

}